# php can't connect to remote database from xampp on windows (remote access enabled on my ip)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have got a problem with my xampp on windows 7. Everythings work fine except when I try to connect to a remote database from my localhost. I've already enabled the remote access on the mysql server for my ip address and I've tried to turn off the windows firewall.

It seems like something prevents the outgoing connections from my localhost to remote host.

Someone can help me?

Thank you

CA

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on your MySQL server, it could be the user you are logging in as (against the DB) has localhost as it's hostname try setting the host name to % for the MySql login

Comment: Please excersize caution when modifying allowed hosts on the database

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The mysql-server settings seem correct, I've tried to log in from a linux machine in the same way and it has no problem. Also I've checked the user log in and it is correct too..

Answer (score 0):

What ip did you insert?

Time ago I had problems to connect to my localhost from an external pc/tablet that was in my local net. Finally the problem was solved when I used as ip to connect from a different pc where xammp was installed this: "http://192.168.1.128:80" Maybe is this